# How do i install ubuntu 12.04 inside windows without downloading it through the wubi installer?

Tags: installation, wubi

I tried mounting and image of the .ISO file using Demon tools and then running it...

It worked!! The installer ran but there was no third option to install the Ubuntu inside Windows.....

Could you please provide me a link from where I can download the ISO file with the inside Windows option?? Because I want to install this software even in the unavailability of internet connection.

Thank you very much in advance. :-)

Comment: Note if you're using the 64-bit ISO then you need a different version of [`wubi.exe`](http://people.canonical.com/~evand/wubi/precise/wubi-r273-signed.exe) anyway due to it having the wrong kernel: https://code.launchpad.net/~bcbc/wubi/lp1134770

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for here.
Do you want to run Ubuntu *inside* your Windows install? If so, try a virtual machine - virtualbox is pretty good.

If you want to install it *alongside* your Windows installation, first things first you need to check whether or not you have any spare partitions on your hard drive.
Most hard drive can only take 4 "real" partitions, and Windows OEM has a tendency to eat up all 4 of them, I have yet to figure out what each of them does (I don't really care much for Windows, after all) but typically one of them will be a recovery section.

Run a live version of Ubuntu, and when you're in open the Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T). Type

```
sudo gparted
```

That will tell you what the usage of the partitions looks like. If you have 4 distinct areas blocked off, you can't install Ubuntu alongside Windows without doing some magic to the hard drive.

Let me know what the gparted read looks like (don't touch anything on gparted... it has the potential to do some serious damage), just post a screenshot, and I'll take a look.